# Converting an HTML Document to Selector based index file

Tags: html, css, xpath, css-selectors

I'm looking for some sort of tool that can take an html document and pump out a selector based representation of the file.

For example:

```
<div>
Some text
  <ul class="foo">
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

And output a flat text file in the spirit of:

```
 div
 div #text Some text
 div ul.foo li Frist
 div ul.foo li Second
```

The purpose of doing this would be to make a predicate function of some sort that would be able to compare two HTML pages and tell to what degree they match and explicitly be able to tell in isolation how much of the content or layout is different.

(For the curious, this is for the QA phase of a relatively large data migration project)

Comment: If you're looking for a tool to do this, instead of writing that tool yourself, then maybe this question isn't programming-related.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Chris.

 I do, however, believe that not writing code is as much programming as writing code.

Comment: It's that this seemed to me to be such a short/easy coding problem that I would have wanted to code it, instead of looking for an existing tool: 1) Load the HTML into a DOM 2) Walk/iterate the nodes in the DOM 3) Print each node (including its ancestor informatin) in the format you specified.

Comment: This is not related to data mining. Please use only appropriate tags. Thank you. Replaced the tag with "xpath", as the selectors essentially are xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found on another forum a program called haml which seems to do this exactly. For future reference:

http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/howtos/templates/haml